# How to use a declarative pattern on Observables that watch the network?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have been trying to learn about the declarative pattern/approach in rxjs, which from my understanding it to not use `.subscribe()` directly in the typescript itself and use the `async` pipe instead.

I have a class that holds data about an image, and some of that data is a `tags` property which is an array of strings. Through the UI you can add/remove tags to this property. When you save a new item the value goes to the server via a websocket, and the socket will send a list of all the items tags back (including the newly added one).

So, I created a listener that listens for when the websocket responds with data related to the image tags. When it sees this message it should update all the tags in the object for this image.

Something like this pseudo code below:

```js
interface FileInfo {
  tags: string[];
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="image$ | async as image">
      <div *ngFor="let tag of image.tags">{{tag}}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  image = new BehaviorSubject<FileInfo | null>(null);
  image$ = this.image.asObservable();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.websocket.on('tags:image').pipe(
      map(i => i.data) // i.data is an array of strings
      tap(strs => this.image.value = strs)
    );
  }
}
```

Now when a message comes back it should update the image object and re-render the component.
Without using a subscribe on the `this.websocket.on()` how can this pattern/approach be possible? All this does is watch the network and modify a property on an object.

---

I modified the above to to this pattern, but I don't really like that I have to manage more than one property now when doing `.next()`, this approach doesn't seem right and seems like it is easy to get `image.tags` out of sync the value of `tags$`.

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="image$ | async as image">
      <div *ngFor="let tag of tags$ | async">{{tag}}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  image = new BehaviorSubject<FileInfo | null>(null);
  image$ = this.image.asObservable();

  tags = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);
  tags$ = merge(this.tags, this.websocket.on('tags:image')).pipe(
    map(i => i.data) // i.data is an array of strings
  );

  ngOnInit() {
   // I want to get rid of this subscribe too
   // However this is the next
   this.manageService.$collectionEvents.subscribe(event => {
     this.image.next(event.image);
     this.tags.next(event.image.tags);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of making a behaviorsubject and use asObservable, you can assign the observable you have built to `this.image$` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like this (I've just made an observable `data$` to simulate your web socket response):

```js
  image$ = new Observable<FileInfo>();

  ngOnInit() {
    const data$ = of({ data: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'] });
    this.image$ = data$.pipe(
      map((i) => {
        return { tags: i.data };
      })
    );
  }
```

In your context

```js
  image$ = new Observable<FileInfo>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.image$ = this.websocket.on('tags:image').pipe(
      map((i) => {
        return { tags: i.data };
      })
    );
  }
```

The async pipe will automatically subscribe to `image$` and also unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. It also handles updating html whenever the observable receives a new value.

Here's a stackblitz where I simulate the observable value changing every second: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m2digv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: But this will never execute because it isn't subscribed to....

Comment: The async pipe automatically subscribes - try it : )

Comment: but I don't want to subscribe to the socket in the template

Comment: that will cause `FileInfo.tags` in the `image` subscription to get out of sync with the server

Comment: Your template remains exactly the same, that's why I didn't include it in my answer, I can make a stackblitz. The async pipe will update html whenever the observable receives a new value.

Comment: yes please, a stackblitz would be helpful!

Comment: Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m2digv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: huh... I didn't know you could do what you did with `data$` and `image$` on line 26 I thought that you always had to subscribe to each one (one for data and one for image).

Comment: Yeah it's pretty neat. Nothing actually gets executed until something subscribes, each observable is just a code block to be executed later. `pipe` just tacks on more code to the end of it. So you just subscribe when you have your fully constructed code block.

Comment: I also didn't know that re-assigning to `image$` would trigger the template rebuild, I thought it was just on a `.next()` call. Very cool!

Comment: Yeah that's the async pipe subscribing and then triggering a template render on change. Magic.

Comment: So, when I have more data in the object, it seems to just replace it with what is in there, so `{url:'...', exif:[], tags:['a','b']}` all seem to get replaced with `{tags:['a','b','c']}` can I merge the current value with the new value?

Comment: Yeah I think you're looking at the `mergeMap` pipe operator, might want to open a whole new question for that.

Comment: zip might also work too

Comment: Yeah I'm not too familiar with all the operators, you might be able to find someone that knows more if you open another question.